# how to extract inline CSS style without style key in XHTML using beautiful soup

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, xhtml, frontend

```
<p height="1em" width="0" align="justify">“<span><i>
There’s the feather bed element here brother, ach! and not only that! There’s an attraction here—here you have the end of the world, an anchorage, a quiet haven, the navel of the earth, the three fishes that are the foundation of the world, the essence of pancakes, of savoury fish-pies, of the evening samovar, of soft sighs and warm shawls, and hot stoves to sleep on—as snug as though you were dead, and yet you’re alive—the advantages of both at once.
</i></span>”</p>
```

with bs4, I wanna use p["style"] to extract height="1em" width="0" align="justify" info, but ofc it will throw a key error. How to parse inline css style like this?

correct: actually this html sentence doesn't css inline style, just old styled attribute. so just iterate through the attributes

Comment: this xhtml is compiled from a mobi file

Comment: But this is not an inline style, it's invalid HTML. You can't expect BeautifulSoup to be fed any old invalid HTML and come up with the result you like.

Comment: u r right, this not even css, i will think up a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) soup and css selector.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<p height="1em" width="0" align="justify"><span><i>
There’s the feather bed element here brother, ach! and not only that! There’s an attraction here—here you have the end of the world, an anchorage, a quiet haven, the navel of the earth, the three fishes that are the foundation of the world, the essence of pancakes, of savoury fish-pies, of the evening samovar, of soft sighs and warm shawls, and hot stoves to sleep on—as snug as though you were dead, and yet you’re alive—the advantages of both at once.
</i></span></p>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('p[height]')['height'])
print(soup.select_one('p[width]')['width'])
print(soup.select_one('p[align]')['align'])
```

**Output**:

```
1em
0
justify
```

Comment: is there anyway to get whole css declaration at once like:
height="1em" width="0" align="justify"

Comment: @JianhaoLuo : No, You have fetch each attribute value like i mentioned.See Beautifulsoup document I have linked with.

Comment: regarding to the this question, its resolved, but i will add more details to describe my situation later

Comment: but to describe the situation, I will add my own answer later

Comment: @JianhaoLuo : The HTML you have provided I have provided solution based on that.If you looking after something else then post that html and describe what you after.Thanks.